# My silent installation restarts the machine after Prerequisite installation but doesnot complete installation of the application

Tags: installation, silent, silent-installer, prerequisites, installshield-2015

I am trying to upgrade the application with command C:\Windows\TEMP\MyApplication_64_7.4.10.8016.exe /s /v"/qn ADDLOCAL=ALL"

It is installing the .net 4.7.2 framework Prerequisite, reboots the system but doesn't complete the installation.

However, when I run the exe from double click, it restarts and completes the installation, which is the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to set the [REBOOT property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reboot) to Supress or ReallySupress in your installer.

Comment: Have tried with both settings(Supress\ReallySupress) without luck, currently I am working on creating a scheduled task (which would trigger on system start up) before the installation starts, so that I can continue the installation after machine reboot  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/boot-trigger-example--c---

Comment: Yup, there is a registry setting you can set to relaunch your install on reboot. I would also log the install to make sure that nothing is resetting your REBOOT property.

Answer (score 0):

The approach(mentioned in above comment) of creating a scheduled task before starting of installation worked for me, in that scheduled task, I re-launched the installer